# How to remove a specific (bottom) border from p:row in p:panelGrid?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I need to remove only a bottom border as displayed by `<p:row>` in [`<p:panelGrid>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml). I attempted the following.

CSS :

```css
.panelgrid-cell-noborder.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

XHTML :

```
<p:panelGrid style="width: 100%;">
    <p:row>
        <p:column>a</p:column>
        <p:column>b</p:column>
    </p:row>

    <p:row>
        <p:column styleClass="panelgrid-cell-noborder">c</p:column>
        <p:column styleClass="panelgrid-cell-noborder">d</p:column>
    </p:row>

    <p:row>
        <p:column>e</p:column>
        <p:column>f</p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

The bottom border from the middle row is expected to be removed but it does not.

How to remove the bottom border from the middle row, in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every cell has border in this case by default, so you should cancel bottom border and top border of the row below:

XHTML:

```
<p:panelGrid style="width: 100%;">
    <p:row>
        <p:column>a</p:column>
        <p:column>b</p:column>
    </p:row>

    <p:row>
        <p:column styleClass="panelgrid-cell-noborder-bottom">c</p:column>
        <p:column styleClass="panelgrid-cell-noborder-bottom">d</p:column>
    </p:row>

    <p:row>
        <p:column styleClass="panelgrid-cell-noborder-top">e</p:column>
        <p:column styleClass="panelgrid-cell-noborder-top">f</p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell.panelgrid-cell-noborder-bottom {
    border-bottom: none;
}
.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell.panelgrid-cell-noborder-top {
    border-top: none;
}
```

Also, your CSS was incorrect, you put `ui-panelgrid` together with the cell style, check that in my example too.

**Edit:**

You'll probably have to override theme styles too if you have them by default, because there are borders defined in both theme and primefaces styles, you could try adding this for example:

```
/* cancel border defined in aristo theme */
.ui-panelgrid .ui-widget-content{
    border: none;
}
/* extra: you can add this if you want to recover the same color you cancelled above  */
.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the bottom border is not removed by using these CSS classes (I just copy/pasted the code. It does not function).

Comment: @Tiny Sorry, I had a custom theme and it was working for me. Now I created a project from scratch and noticed that default theme was also present but with the class `.ui-widget-content`, try my edit and keep me updated :)

Comment: The bottom order has been removed. Thank you. :)